# Java - order a collections by number of objects in each list?

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, java-stream

```
 Collection<List<Person>> personsByDepartment=
                persons.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDepartment))
                        .values();
```

I have the following `Collection` above that groups a list of People into lists based off their department. This is working as expected.

How can I ensure this list is `sorted` so that the list with most amount of people in it is first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare the lists by their size. You could stream the values again to sort:

```
Collection<List<Person>> personsByDepartment = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDepartment))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .sorted((l1, l2) -> Integer.compare(l2.size(), l1.size()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit:** As Michael pointed out in comments the same comparator can be written as:

```
Comparator.<List<Person>>comparingInt(List::size).reversed()
```

It's more obvious, that the ordering is being reversed.